# Sort files by the type of file

Tags: java, sorting, file, enum, lambda

I need to sort files by the type of the File. To accomplish the task I first wrote the code below:

> ```
> private static Comparator SortByFileType() {
>
>     return Comparator.comparing((File f) -> {
>         String probeContentType = null;
>         try {
>             probeContentType = Files.probeContentType(f.toPath());
>             if (probeContentType ==null) {
>                 probeContentType = "probeContentTypeIsNull";
>             }
>         } catch (IOException e) {
>         }
>         return probeContentType;
>     });
> }
> ```

Then I needed to perform different sorts, so I decided to make an `enum` of sorts, but I wasn't able to pass the above code to the enum. I instead rewrote the above code as given below:

```
public enum Sort implements Comparator<File> {

/**
 * Compare files by the name of the File A<->Z
 *
 */
ByFileName {



        },
/**
 * Compare Files by the Type of file
 */
ByFileType {

        @Override
        public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
            String fileType1 = "";
            String fileType2 = "";

            try {
                fileType1 = Files.probeContentType(f1.toPath());
                fileType2 = Files.probeContentType(f2.toPath());
            } catch (IOException ex) {

            }

            if (fileType1 == null) {
                fileType1 = "probeContentTypeIsNull";
            }
            if (fileType2 == null) {
                fileType2 = "probeContentTypeIsNull";
            }

            return fileType1.compareTo(fileType2);
        }

    }
}
```

Now I need to know two things:

1. Can we turn the code passed to the `ByFileType` enum into a lambda?
2. Can the code passed to the `ByFileType` be optimized and improved?

Answer (score 2):

This is a great concept to work with. Creating an enum of comparators is a clever way to make it easy to manage the sort order of file collections.

The name concerns me. I realize that `Sort` is convenient, but enums are normally given a "noun" name. "Sort" is a verb - something you do, not a noun which is a "thing". I would call it `Sorter`, or even `FileSorter`. Adding `File` to it makes code more readable.

Additionally, enum members are normally in all-uppercase and under-score separated.... so, `BY_FILE_NAME` instead of `ByFileName`.

Adding the "File" to be `FileSorter` you no longer need to have `File` as part of the enum names, so you will have: `FileSorter.BY_NAME`.

I believe you have truncated some code from the `ByFileName` enum. It does not compile without the override of the compare method. I'll just claim it is because of how you summarized things for this question.

Now, about the functional aspects. I agree, the override is a mess, and can be sorted out quite easily. First up, what you want to do is pass a comparator in as the constructor for the enum, and then use that comparator as a tool in the compare function.... like this:

```
private final Comparator<File> comp;

private FileSorter(Comparator<File> comp) {
    this.comp = comp;
}

@Override
public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
    return comp.compare(o1, o2);
}
```

That makes the actual enum guts really simple, not it's just a case of setting up the enum members.... the ones that are easy are things like size, and name sorts:

```
BY_NAME(Comparator.comparing(File::getName))
```

and

```
BY_SIZE(Comparator.comparingLong(File::length))
```

Taking your base code though, for sorting by type, you had:

> ```
> return Comparator.comparing((File f) -> {
>     String probeContentType = null;
>     try {
>         probeContentType = Files.probeContentType(f.toPath());
>         if (probeContentType ==null) {
>             probeContentType = "probeContentTypeIsNull";
>         }
>     } catch (IOException e) {
>     }
>     return probeContentType;
> });
> ```

That code is 'ugly' because it is hard to follow the logic through, the empty catch block is a mess, and the blocked lambda `(File f) -> {....}` type expressions make me want to create a function for them, so I do....

I created the function:

```
private static final String extractType(File f) {
    try {
        String probeContentType = Files.probeContentType(f.toPath());
        return probeContentType == null ? "probeContentTypeIsNull" : probeContentType;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note how I have a correctly-scoped `probeContentType` variable, and I use a return in both the successful, and catch-side of the try/catch block. The logic is now very visible. That function extracts just the file's type. How is it used, though?

```
BY_TYPE(Comparator.comparing(FileSorter::extractType)),
```

Putting this all together, I have the following code which I believe is quite simple, and readable:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.Comparator;

public enum FileSorter implements Comparator<File> {

    BY_TYPE(Comparator.comparing(FileSorter::extractType)),
    BY_NAME(Comparator.comparing(File::getName)),
    BY_SIZE(Comparator.comparingLong(File::length));

    private static final String extractType(File f) {
        try {
            String probeContentType = Files.probeContentType(f.toPath());
            return probeContentType == null ? "probeContentTypeIsNull" : probeContentType;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private final Comparator<File> comp;

    private FileSorter(Comparator<File> comp) {
        this.comp = comp;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
        return comp.compare(o1, o2);
    }
}
```

Comment: A very explanatory and detailed answered. +1000 I wish I could